# Is there a way to include null columns in my json output when using apex_json

Tags: json, rest, plsql, null

I have a number of stored procedures in my 19c database and I am using the apex_json package to convert the results of a cursor to json for a rest api.

Recently I discovered that some of the columns I am selecting have null values in them, so when the json is generated that column is not included in the output.  Unfortunately when I use knnockout to bind the json to my web page, the viewmodel javascript fails because there is no column to bind in some cases.

So my question is there a way to configure apex_json either when opening it or when writing it to tell the package that I want to include "null" or something similar in the json output for null columns in the input cursor?

Sample stored procedure:

```
create or replace procedure  my_demo
) as
    l_cur sys_refcursor;
begin
    open l_cur for
        select name,email,phonenumber
    from temp
    order by name;

-- return the resultset in json format
apex_json.open_object;
apex_json. write('data',l_cur);
apex_json.close_object;

end my_demo;
```

Current output:

```
{
"data" : [
{"name":"Barney","email":"barney@example.com","phonenumber":"555.1212"},
{"name":"Fred","email":"fred@example.com"},
{"name":"Robert","email"robert@example.com","phonenumber":"555.2323"}
]}
```

Expected output:

```
{
"data" : [
{"name":"Barney","email":"barney@example.com","phonenumber":"555.1212"},
{"name":"Fred","email":"fred@example.com","phonenumber":""},
{"name":"Robert","email"robert@example.com","phonenumber":"555.2323"}
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically you can't use null as a value, however you can use an empty string, which should be easily convertible to a null value in your program.
It would be something like this:

[{ data {
name: ''
}
}]

Answer (score 0):

```
    DECLARE
  c sys_refcursor;
  l_sql varchar2(4000) := 'select name,email,phonenumber
    from temp
    order by name';
   l_xml xmltype;
   l_ctx dbms_xmlgen.ctxHandle;
BEGIN
  open c for  l_sql;
    /* converts the results of a SQL query to a canonical XML format */
    l_ctx := dbms_xmlgen.newContext(c); 
    /* Sets NULL handling options */
    dbms_xmlgen.setNullHandling(l_ctx, dbms_xmlgen.EMPTY_TAG);
    l_xml := dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(l_ctx); 
    dbms_xmlgen.closecontext(l_ctx); 
  close c; 
  
  apex_json.initialize_clob_output;      
  apex_json.open_object;
  
  /* I don't know why but 3-th parameter doesn't work for me,
     always returns null which is ok in my case */
  apex_json.write('rowset', l_xml, true);
  
  apex_json.close_all;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_line(apex_json.get_clob_output);
END;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).